# Microsoft SQL Server - Query with huge results, causes ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait issue

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Java application requesting about 2.4 million records from a Microsoft SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3))

The application runs fine on all hosts, except one.  On this host, the application is able to retrieve data on some occasions.  But on some others, it hangs.

Monitoring the MS Sql server indicates that the SPID associated with the query is in an ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait state.

There are a few links online that talk about it.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joesack/2009/01/08/troubleshooting-async_network_io-networkio/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6db233d5-8892-4f8a-88c7-b72d0fc59ca9/very-high-asyncnetworkio?forum=sqldatabaseengine

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1df2cab8-33ca-4870-9daf-ed333a64630c/network-packet-size-and-delay-by-sql-server-sending-data-to-client?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Based on the above, the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO means 2 things:
1. Application is slow to process the results
2. Network between application and DB has some issues.

For #1 above, We analyzed using tcpdumps and found that in the cases where the query goes into ASYNC_NETWORK_IO state, the application server's tcp connection has a window size that oscillates between 0 and a small number, and eventually remains stuck at 0.  Based on some more analysis, aspects related to firewalls between DB and application have also been mostly ruled out.

So I am staring at #2, unable to understand what could possibly go wrong. All the more baffling because the same code has been running under similar data loads for more than a year now.  And it also runs fine on other hosts.

The JDBC driver being used is sqljdbc4-4.0.jar.
This by default has an adaptive buffering feature, which does things under the hood to reduce application resources.
We use the default fetch size of 128 (which i believe is not a good one).

So i am going to experiment overriding the default adaptive buffering behavior, though the MS docs suggest that it is good to have adaptive buffering for large result sets.

I will change the connection setting to use selectMethod=cursor.
And also change the fetchSize to 1024.

Now if it does not work:

1. What are some aspects of the problem that are worth investigating.
2. Assuming its still an issue with the client, what other connection settings, network settings should be inspected/changed to make progress?

If it does work consistently, what is the impact of making the connection setting change to selectMethod=cursor

1. On the application side?
2. Database side?

---

Update: I tested the application adding the selectMethod=cursor to the connection.  However, it results in the same issue as above.

Based on discussions with other administrators in the team - at this point the issue may be in the jdbc driver, or on the OS (when it tries to handle the data on the network).

Comment: It's probably running out of memory on that server, swapping itself to death. Your pending change of `selectMethod=cursor` should fix that, especially if your Java code doesn't try to remember all the data, but processes it as it is retrieved.

Comment: @Andreas - This is not the case, as there is no excessive GC activity.  There is sufficient heap size allocated to the process.  No OOM observed.

Comment: I wasn't referring to JVM GC, but OS swapping. If you give the JVM more memory than the OS has available, then it must swap pages. OS memory could be overloaded by other processes, or if it's a VM, the host memory could be overloaded by other VMs. Either way, memory swapping to disk, will slow processing, and excessive swapping will basically stall the process, which is what I referred to a "swapping to death".

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks.  No OS Swapping was observed either.  The box had a lot of free memory without I/O Swapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good amount of discussions with the System admin, Network Admin and Database admin - it was agreed that somewhere in the OS -> Application stack, the data from network wasn't handled. In the meantime, we tested out a solution where we broke down the query to return smaller sized results. So we broke it down to 5 queries, each returning about 500k records.

Now when we ran these queries sequentially, we still ran into the same issue.

However, when we ran the queries in parallel, it always was successful.

Given that the solution worked always we haven't bothered getting to the root cause of the problem anymore.

On another note, the hardware and software running the application was also outdated. It was running Red Hat 5. So, it could well have to do something with that.